# Couldn't trace back NoReverseMatch Error: Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, database

I am once again facing an error that is related to NoReverseMatch. Still, I couldn't find the source. Here is my code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.details, name="details"),
    path("add/", views.add, name="add"),
    path("delete/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.delete, name="delete"),
    path("edit/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("update/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.update, name="update")
]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Aufgabenzettel(models.Model):
    Aufgabeselbst = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Aufgabeselbst}"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from .models import Aufgabenzettel

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/index.html", {
        "Aufgabenliste":Aufgabenzettel.objects.all()
    })

def details(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/details.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Aufgabe = request.POST["Hinzufügen"]
        Aufgabenzettel.objects.create(Aufgabeselbst=Aufgabe)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/add.html")

def delete(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    aufgabenzettel.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

def edit(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel
    })

def update(request):
    if request.method == "post":
        Aufgabejetzt = request.POST["Bearbeiten"]
        Aufgabejetzt.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html")
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Meine Aufgaben</h1>
    <ol>
        {% for Aufgabeselbst in Aufgabenliste %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'details' Aufgabeselbst.id %}"> 
                    {{ Aufgabeselbst }}
                </a>
                <form action="{% url 'delete' Aufgabeselbst.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Löschen</button>
                </form>
                <form action="{% url 'edit' Aufgabeselbst.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" value="{{ details }}">Bearbeiten</button>
                </form>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    <h2>
        <a href="{% url 'add' %}">Neue Aufgabe erstellen</a>
    </h2>
{% endblock %}
```

**add.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Füge eine neue Aufgabe hinzu</h1>
    <form action="{% url 'add' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="Hinzufügen" placeholder="Neue Aufgabe">
        <button type="submit">Hinzufügen</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**edit.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'update' aufgabenzettel.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="Bearbeiten" value="{{details}}">
        <button type="submit">Bearbeiten</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**details.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ details }}</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

I try to edit an existing task by updating the database. Though, this error occurs: *Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['aufgabenzettel/update/(?P<aufgabenzettel_id>[0-9]+)$']* and the error is marked in line 33 of views.py with `return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/edit.html", {`

As always I am very grateful for every hint or solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
{% url 'update' aufgabenzettel.id %}
```

with

```
{% url 'update' details.id %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The Error disappeared, but now it says: *update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'aufgabenzettel_id'. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: See your "def update()" and the difference to "def edit()". You forgot the argument in the view definition

Comment: I've seen it, but what is the additional argument? Because it doesn't work with "def update(request, aufgabenzettel_id):" even though I defined the path "    path("update/<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.update, name="update")". I still get the exact same error as described above...

Comment: Please always provide the error trace and as there are several things to debug one by one I would also recommend to update the changed code here or place a new question. I do not inderstand clearly which "error above" you mean.